# Does Link exchange technique become down my site?

Tags: seo, backlinks, sitelinks

I have travel site that has some link exchange to another with free links. Last time, I and some friend use link exchange to give my links has good on PageRank and search engine that can give more visitor.

Recent, I read some article on forum that know links exchange is violate, [this article I get from Google](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/66356?hl=en). Does Link exchange technique become down my site? What should I do? Does I must delete my link exchange page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Matt Cutts has a video titled "Does linking my two sites together violate the quality guidelines?"

See it and make your own conclusions:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=x0-jw_PfwtY

Comment: Did you have some research about it? Maybe I can see your blog/web that has good page rank

Comment: From my experience I can answer you that it still works, but I would not recommend you to use this techniques if you use forward-looking strategy.